# JPA Entity Default constructor

Tags: java, jpa

In JPA entity class , What is the use of having constructor either default or argument constructor. I have read many articles regarding that. But none of that give an detailed explanation about that.

Comment: I guess you came across this question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027385/empty-constructors-and-setters-on-jpa-entites

Answer (score 2):

So that entity manager could create an entity and then initialise the fields through the setters.

For example here:

```
MeEntity entity = em.find(MyEntity.class, id);
```

See here as well: [Java default constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488716/java-default-constructor)

Comment: Then what is the use of creating the default constructor automatically by the jvm

Comment: Default constructor is only assumed/generated when there's no other constructor.